# 2 Ponts to affine transform data array

Tags: javascript, typescript

The input data

```
{
  from: {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  },
  to: {
    x: 10,
    y: 10
  }
}
```

The output

```
/**
 * Transform data represented by affine transformation
 */
export type Transform = [[number, number, number], [number, number, number]];
```

How will i be able to convert this 2 from/to points to affine transform compat data array?
more description for Transform - https://www.figma.com/plugin-docs/api/Transform/

Answer (score 0):

#### How to get from one point to another is not enough to describe an affine transform

Think about it:

- It could be a translation, in which case there is only one option.
- It could be a rotation, of which there is one possible transformation for every possible centre of rotation.
- It could be a scaling, and again there are a wide range of combinations of centre of scaling and scale factor that would do it.